# Where can I find a list of all 3DS titles available in the 3DS eShop?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

I am planning to get a 3DS, and wanted to know what sort of games are up on the 3DS eShop.

I tried checking the Nintendo website, but it only shows a list of "featured" titles, not the entire shop catalog. I assume they want you to look using the device itself (and thereby hopefully buy a game or two)

For those of us without a 3DS, is this information available elsewhere?

Comment: I think the question title should be changed to "Where can I find a listing of 3DS eShop titles online?" With the current title I came in here thinking someone was looking for pirated games.

Comment: Yeah now that I read it again it does sound rather dodgy. I will change the title.

Comment: I edited the title to specifically make it a question; I think the question itself is a good example of asking how to find a list rather than asking for the list itself ... the latter [don't work well on these sites](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/776/8366).

Comment: @Dave - that was my problem. I knew list questions didn't work well, and I struggled to make it clear that I didn't want a list, but a place to find a list. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wikipedia has a list of [Virtual Consoles Games for the 3DS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Virtual_Console_games_for_Nintendo_3DS_%28North_America%29) (which include current and upcoming games), and also a list of [DSiWare Games and Applications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DSiWare) (DSiWare works on the 3DS).

Comment: I forgot about the DSiWare games would work as well. Thanks for pointing that out!